# Get HTML code from $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to get innerHTML of `$(this)`:

```
var html=$(this).html();
```

So for example if $(this) refers to `<div class="hello">Some <strong>HTML</strong> here.</div>`, `var html` will be `Some <strong>HTML</strong> here.`.

Great, but what I want to get is the whole HTML for `$(this)`, including `<div class="hello">` and `</div>`.

How can I do that please?

Comment: var html=$(this).parent().html();

Comment: @Pramendra That won't work if this' parent has other children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
$(this).attr('outerHTML');
```

or

```
$(this)[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: It will be infinite recursion or an element to have it's outerHTML as an attribute, since attributes are part of the outerHTML

Comment: It's `prop` from 1.6+. Thank you.

Comment: According to quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html), outerHTML is not supported by Firefox.

Comment: I like the [0].outerHTML solution.  The first one, however, did not work for me.

Comment: Why not just `this.outerHTML`?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery can't do it straight out, so you need to trick it. You basically clone (this), put it into an element you can get the HTML from, and then remove it.

Example:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html();
```

Comment: Thank you, Shane. But I'd say that outerHTML version is faster. Nice chaining though.

Comment: I agree outerHTML would be ideal but unfortunately it isn't inter operable! See [compatibility on W3C](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html). Up to you and your application, though!

Comment: I'm in a pickle. Your answer is the one everyone should see as it's interoperable. However, for my use case, outerHTML is faster and the correct answer for me for this particular case...

Answer (score 1):

Considering your HTML using .outerHTML() from https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml you will get the whole element.

```
var HTML = $(".hello").outerHTML();
```

The HTML variable is equal '<div class="hello">Some <strong>HTML</strong> here.</div>';

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your specific example:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($( this ).clone()).remove().html();
```